# Android ListView's OnItemClickListener did not catch inner item's click event

Tags: android, listview

In my listview's item, there are many components. A component that I'd like to click is the ImageButton named kickOutBtn.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_pane"
    android:paddingVertical="6dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:paddingHorizontal="28dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/colorGray"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="nickname"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_image"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="10dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fake_click_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/owner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="manager"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="10dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/kickOutBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
        android:tint="@color/colorBlack"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

These are in a same location in a view.

I mean, the Textview is located in the center of the ImageButton.

And if the ListView item's target is a manager, I want to make its list item's ImageButton invisible and open the Textview that says manager, and if not, I want to make its list item's ImageButton show the opposite, and I want to make the owner Textview invisible. (default is that imagebutton is invisible and textview is visible)

To do that, I tried to this code.

// getView in ListAdapter

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navi_list_menu_item, null);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        ImageButton kick_btn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.kickOutBtn);
        TextView supervisor_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.owner);

        if (roomSupervisor.equals(mNavItems.get(i).fb_uid)) {
            kick_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            supervisor_tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (roomSupervisor.equals(SessionInfo.fb_uid)) {
                kick_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                kick_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        return view;
    }
```

// OnItemClickListener in Activity

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = (adapterView, view, i, l) -> {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.kickOutBtn) {
            Log.d(TAG, "kick");
            popupDialog(i);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, i + "is pushed");
        }
    };
```

In this situtation, the kick ImageButton is not clickable... (list row's click event is well performed)

Whenever I click that button, there is no response in onItemClickListener in Activity...

What should I do...?

Comment: Could you post full code of Adapter ?

Comment: Try change `supervisor_tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` to `supervisor_tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);`.

Answer (score 0):

So your activity implements OnItemClickListener. You also need to set the click listener to your activity then. Have you done that?

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(activity)
```

Comment: I also did that like this. `mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);`

Comment: mDrawerList is a ListView!

Comment: Oh I just initialized OnItemClickListener as a variable @Leo Lamas

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the listener in your adpter like this:

```
if (roomSupervisor.equals(mNavItems.get(i).fb_uid)) {
        kick_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        supervisor_tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (roomSupervisor.equals(SessionInfo.fb_uid)) {
            kick_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            kick_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
 kick_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do what you want here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is recommended to use `RecyclerView` over `ListView`, so I have used `RecyclerView` to address your issue.
I have created a data class which will be used in item view of `RecyclerView`.

**Data Class**

```
 class Item {
    String nickName;
    boolean isManager;
    Item(String nickName, boolean isManager){
        this.nickName = nickName;
        this.isManager = isManager;
    }
  }
```

**Recycler View Adapter**

```
    static class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>{
    List<Item> items;

    RecyclerAdapter(List<Item> itemList){
        items = itemList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (items.get(position).isManager){
            holder.owner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.kickBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else {
            holder.owner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.kickBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        holder.bind(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView owner;
        ImageButton kickBtn;
        TextView profileView;
        RecyclerViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            profileView = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
            owner = view.findViewById(R.id.owner);
            kickBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.kickOutBtn);
            owner.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                items.get(getAdapterPosition()).isManager = false;
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
            });
            kickBtn.setOnClickListener(v ->{
                items.get(getAdapterPosition()).isManager = true;
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
            });
        }
        void bind(Item item){
            profileView.setText(item.nickName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Recycler View's xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And finally, set the adapter to Recycler View like below:

```
   RecyclerView recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
 // Just creating sample list for testing . You could customize your data class as per your requirement.
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new Item("Choco",true));
    items.add(new Item("Nrusingha",false));
    items.add(new Item("Barbie",true));
    items.add(new Item("Uttam",false));
    items.add(new Item("Smruti",false));
    items.add(new Item("Choco",true));
    items.add(new Item("Nrusingha",true));
    items.add(new Item("Barbie",true));
    items.add(new Item("Uttam",false));
    items.add(new Item("Smruti",true));
    RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(items);


    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
```